# ¿Como habilito un input disabled al seleccionar un select con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo un select con dos valores (permitir y no permitir), y debajo de este select dos input disabled para digitar la contraseña, la idea es que si selecciona el valor permitir automaticamente me habilite los input para digitar la contraseña...

Dejo el codigo sencillo del html...

```
       <select class="form-control m-b-10">
         <option value="false">No permitir 1</option>
         <option value="true">Permitir 2</option>
       </select>

<input type="password" name="pass" disabled>
<input type="password" name="pass1" disabled>
```

Agradeceria el interes..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puede ser algo así (previamente debes cargar jQuery):

```
$( function(){
    $('select').on('change', function(){
        var disabled = $(this).val() == 'true' ? false : true;
        $('input[name=pass]').prop('disabled', disabled);
        $('input[name=pass1]').prop('disabled', disabled);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hola @javiertapia ¿dejo mi codigo html tal cual?

Comment: Hola @Daniel. Para solucionar lo que preguntaste al inicio, no necesitas hacer nada en el html. Pero si vas a usar el dato del _select_, o si hay otros _select_ en tu formulario, deberías ponerle un `name` para distinguirlo. En este caso, deberías modificar también el código javascript que escribí.

Comment: Excelente men te agradezco resto...

Answer (score 2):

Verifica con esto, en cada cambio del select, valida el valor del opción

```
$( function(){
    $('select').on('change', function(this){
        if((this).val() == 'true')
        {
            $('input[name=pass]').prop('disabled', disabled);
            $('input[name=pass1]').prop('disabled', disabled);
        } 
        else 
       {
            $("input[name=pass]").removeAttr("disabled");
            $('input[name=pass1]').removeAttr("disabled");
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo dándole un id a tu select, en este caso le he dado `estado`. Luego en jQuery verificas si hay algo seleccionado usando [`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) y estableces la propiedad de tu input a `true` o `false` según el valor de la variable llamada `sino`.

> ***Buenas prácticas de jQuery:*** He usado el método [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)para establecer el estado del input a enabled/disabled, ya que jQuery recomienda usar este método para encontrar o cambiar las propiedades de un elemento del DOM: *To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or **disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method**.*  Aquí jQuery nos explica en cuáles casos es mejor usar el método [`atrr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Para que funcione solo tienes que agregar `id="estado"`al final de tu select, como muestra el ejemplo.

**Nota:**

Quizá haya que verificar lo que pasa en cada input. Por ejemplo si selecciones permitir y se activa el input, escribes valores y luego seleccionas no permitir... he añadido un fragmento de código para borrar lo que haya escrito en caso de que el input vuelva al estado desactivado. De paso he aplicado colores de fondo usando [CSS](http://api.jquery.com/css/), sólo para mostrar una posibilidad interesante para los input. :)

Puedes probar el código pulsando en el botón azul Ejecutar.

```html
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>

<!-- Código jQuery -->

$(document).ready(function() 
{
$('#estado').change(function () 
{
    var sino = $(this).val() == 'true' ? false : true;
    $("input[name='pass']").prop('disabled',sino).css("background-color","#0F0");
    $("input[name='pass1']").prop('disabled',sino);

//Validar lo que hay en el input y aplicar css
    if (sino==false)
    {
         $("input[name='pass']").css("background-color","#FEF5CA");
         $("input[name='pass1']").css("background-color","#FEF5CA");

    } else {

         $("input[name='pass']").css("background-color","#7F7F7F");
         $("input[name='pass1']").css("background-color","#7F7F7F");
         $("input[name='pass']").val("");
         $("input[name='pass']").val("");
    }


});
});
</script>

<!-- HTML -->


<select class="form-control m-b-10" id="estado">
<option value="false">No permitir 1</option>
<option value="true">Permitir 2</option>
</select>

<input type="password" name="pass" disabled>
<input type="password" name="pass1" disabled>
```

Answer (score -2):

No te compliques, es más sencillo que todo eso. HABILITAR:

```
document.getElementById("identificador").disabled = "";
```

DESHABILITAR:

```
document.getElementById("identificador").disabled = "disabled";
```